# form_for doesn't save to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I have a very basic Rails application that has some standard scaffolded CRUD resources that worked just fine. All of a sudden, and I can't figure out why, the "form_for"s are no longer saving or updating the DB. However, everything works just fine in console. I am getting no errors -- just a redirect back to the 'new' page because of an unsuccessful save attempt. I've restarted servers, restarted everything, bundled again, migrated, etc. Nothing seems to work. How can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try temporarily changing `@model.save` to `@model.save!` in one of the relevant controllers.

This tells Rails to throw an exception if saving fails, instead of it's usual approach (redirecting to `new`, usually). Most likely you have a validation error, but whether or not that's the case, if you do this, you'll get an actual description of the error that occurred when the controller tried to save your updated model. That should give you somewhere to start debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It turns out I just hadn't closed a </form>...Time to refactor into partials.